# Laravel charset UTF-8 with sqlsrv

Tags: sql-server, laravel

What should I do to correctly store data with special characters (UTF-8) in SQL Server (2014)? My HTML page is UTF-8 coded, the column in the database table is type *nvarchar*, the connection charset is set to UTF-8, but the string

> Haïti couplées à la capacité

is stored as

> 慈꿃楴挠畯汰꧃獥쌠₠慬挠灡捡瑩꧃

or sometimes

> ????????? ??????

in the table. I am using Laravel 5 with vagrant homestead. Here are the connection parameters:

```
'sqlsrv' => array(
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => 'DB_HOST',
        'database' => 'DB_DATABASE',
        'username' => 'DB_USERNAME',
        'password' => 'DB_PASSWORD',
        'prefix'   => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    ),
```

and have set following in freetds.conf:

```
[global]
tds version = 8.0
client charset = UTF-8
```

Comment: What is you database server collation(f.i mine is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)...also check the default language for the login role

Comment: Do you solved yet?

Comment: I have this problem when using the sybase driver on ubuntu (with freeTDS). This doesn't happen when running the same Laravel application from a Windows Server (IIS).

Comment: Also having the same problem, did u ever find a solution?

Comment: You can try the MS driver for Linux which came out in January 2017 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server-on-linux

Answer (score 0):

You can try the MS driver for Linux which came out in January 2017.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server-on-linux

```
#### Script to Install MS SQL Server driver on Ubuntu:
#!/bin/bash
# SQL Server Driver Installer for Laravel Homestead
#
# This script downloads, compiles, and installs the PHP 7 extension
# files for both the native sqlsrv and the PDO pdo_sqlsrv drivers.

echo '=================================================================='
echo ' Get the Microsoft Driver Source Code from Github'
echo '=================================================================='

cd ~
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql.git
cd msphpsql
git checkout PHP-7.0-Linux

echo '=================================================================='
echo ' Run the ODBC Installer Script'
echo '=================================================================='

sh ODBC\ install\ scripts/installodbc_ubuntu.sh

echo '=================================================================='
echo ' Compile and Install the Native sqlsrv Driver'
echo '=================================================================='

cd ~/msphpsql/source/sqlsrv
phpize && ./configure CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 && make
sudo make install
sudo echo "extension=sqlsrv.so" | sudo tee /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini
phpenmod sqlsrv

echo '=================================================================='
echo ' Compile and Install the pdo_sqlsrv Driver'
echo '=================================================================='

cd ~/msphpsql/source/pdo_sqlsrv
phpize && ./configure CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 && make
sudo make install
sudo echo "extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so" | sudo tee /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
sudo phpenmod pdo_sqlsrv

echo '=================================================================='
echo ' Restart the PHP-FPM Service'
echo '=================================================================='

sudo systemctl restart php7.0-fpm.service

echo '=================================================================='
echo ' Clean Up'
echo '=================================================================='
echo "Done."
```

Or use pre-compiled pull and install method with the following steps:

```
wget https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases/download/4.0.8-Linux/Ubuntu16.tar
tar -xf Ubuntu16.tar
sudo cp ./Ubuntu16/*nts*.so /usr/lib/php/20151012
sudo su
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
exit
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql mssql-tools
sudo touch /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
```

How to disable dblib Module:

```
sudo phpdismod pdo_dblib
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and it almost drove me insane.  The script below should work for anyone using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Laravel.  (If you use Forge, paste this in as a post-provision recipe.)

**The part I was missing was the very last line where you add ODBC_App_Unicode_Type=1 to the /etc/odbcinst.ini file.**

I really hope this helps others to avoid the pain I went through!

```
# Add tools & drivers for SQL Server
cd ~
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
apt -y update
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt -y install msodbcsql17
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt -y install mssql-tools
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> /home/forge/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> /home/forge/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> /home/forge/.zshrc
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> /root/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> /root/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> /root/.zshrc
source /root/.zshrc
apt -y install unixodbc-dev
pecl install sqlsrv
pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
printf "; priority=20\nextension=sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini
printf "; priority=30\nextension=pdo_sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
phpenmod -v 7.4 sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
service php7.4-fpm reload
service nginx reload
echo 'ODBC_App_Unicode_Type=1' >> /etc/odbcinst.ini # <-- don't forget this!
# End
```